# How to show current year on layout page?

Tags: angularjs, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication. The application has built-in layout and login page developed using angular. The html, css, angular code is embedded in DLL. However IdentityServer3 still allows you to [customize views](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html)

I want to add a current year in the footer.

```
 <div class='container page-{page}' ng-cloak>
    {pageContent}
    <hr />
    <footer>
       <span>&copy; {{currentdate | currentdate:'yyyy'}} - my company name</span>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Note that `currentdate` is not available property on the controller or viewmodel and I don't have access to modify the viewmodel.

Is there anyway to show current year on layout page?

Answer (score 2):

The quickest paths I could think of, either

### The client side path using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
document.querySelector("footer > span ").innerHTML = currentYear;
```

### The server side path;

- Copy the DefaultViewService code and based on it create your own CustomViewService
- Add your own DateTime property here : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/DefaultViewService.cs#L283
- Create a layout.html including the footer html you mentioned.
- Register that CustomViewService as your IViewService implementation in IdSrv.